# issue with group by when order by is used

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am having difficulty when i try to group by but with using order by statement.

Here is my query

```
create table AllData(NoOfPerson int,NoOfMinutes int,StartTime Datetime);

INSERT INTO AllData VALUES(1,2,GETDATE()),
(0,3,GETDATE()+1),
(3,4,GETDATE()+2),
(2,5,GETDATE()+3),
(0,6,GETDATE()+4),
(3,7,GETDATE()+5),
(2,8,GETDATE()+6);
```

and output from the query

```
select NoOfperson,SUM(NoOfMinutes)NoOfMinutes,MIN(StartTime)StartTime from AllData
group by NoOfperson,StartTime
order by StartTime

NoOfperson  NoOfMinutes StartTime
1               2   2014-02-19 15:44:52.617
0               3   2014-02-20 15:44:52.617
3               4   2014-02-21 15:44:52.617
2               5   2014-02-22 15:44:52.617
0               6   2014-02-23 15:44:52.617
3               7   2014-02-24 15:44:52.617
2               8   2014-02-25 15:44:52.617
```

But i want output should be like

first

```
1  -- 2
0  -- 9
3  -- 11
2  -- 13
```

How can i get this output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try wrap query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT noofperson, 
               Sum(noofminutes) NoOfMinutes, 
               Min(starttime)   StartTime 
        FROM   alldata 
        GROUP  BY noofperson) t 
ORDER  BY noofminutes ASC;
```

or simply:

```
SELECT noofperson, 
       Sum(noofminutes) NoOfMinutes, 
       Min(starttime)   StartTime 
FROM   alldata 
GROUP  BY noofperson 
ORDER  BY noofminutes ASC;
```

Comment: you are grouping by NoOfperson and StartTime, while you exepcting data was grouped only by NoOfperson - try again (i edited my answer)

Comment: No need for the derived table. `ORDER BY` can be added after the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT NoOfperson, NoOfMinutes FROM
(
select NoOfperson,SUM(NoOfMinutes)NoOfMinutes,MIN(StartTime)StartTime from AllData
group by NoOfperson
) AS Data
GROUP BY NoOfperson, NoOfMinutes, StartTime
order by StartTime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NoOfperson, SUM(NoOfMinutes) AS SumNoOfMinutes , MIN(StartTime)StartTime
from AllData
group by NoOfperson
order by SumNoOfMinutes asc ;
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this,

```
select * , 
sum(NoOfMinutes)over(partition by NoOfPerson,NoOfPerson order by  NoOfPerson) 
from @AllData
```